# Twitter Bootstrap ToolTip - ASP.NET Web Forms - Not Working

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

The twitter bootstrap tooltip I have working, however whenever there is a

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAmount" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtAmount"  
                            ErrorMessage="This is a required field.">   
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

on the page, the tooltip doesn't work.

If i comment out the validator, the tooltip works. Thoughts?

Here is the tooltip with the form validation.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" ValidationGroup="rfvAmount">
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAmount" runat="server"    
ControlToValidate="txtAmount" ErrorMessage="This is a required field.">    
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" class="btn btn-success" data-
placement="right" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Send Info"/>
```

Comment: please show your work ?

Comment: when downloaded the boostrap you included all the jquery plugins? please put the code where called the tooltip

Comment: try adding validationgroup to your validator

Comment: It could be that the validator is attaching to the same JS event the input control triggers and not propagating it up, thereby cancelling the bootstrap tooltip...  a theory, but not a proven fact...

Comment: I have tried EVERYTHING I could think of... no luck! Seems like the only way to get it to work is remove the validation controls.. No idea why that would even have an affect.... weird!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the validators from ASP.NET. To resolve this conflict put Bootstrap reference on the bottom of page. That way it will load after ASP.NET controls loads.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
     <%--your ASP.NET validators will load here--%>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>


    $(document).ready(function (){
          doYourStaff();
    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```